# Load mysqli_fetch_object directly into class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, load

I'm currently looking into classes, etc.
I'd like to load something into my object from my database, like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `recepten` WHERE `id` = $id LIMIT 1");
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

$this->id = $obj->id;
$this->titel = $obj->titel;
$this->ingredient = $obj->ingredient;
$this->beschrijving = $obj->beschrijving;
$this->van = $obj->van;
$this->tot = $obj->tot;
$this->altijd = $obj->altijd;
```

As you can see I'm loading `$obj` directly into `$this`. I'm guessing there must be a faster way to do this, I simply can't figure out how... Also google doesn't help.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best method would be to define what columns you want, and by those columns, load it within your `$this`. Note that if these are not defined within the class, they will be public properties within your class.

```
$columns = array('id', 'titel', 'ingredient', 'beschrijving', 'van', 'tot', 'altijd');
$selects = implode('`,`', $columns);
$result  = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `'.$selects.'` FROM `recepten` WHERE `id` = '.$id.' LIMIT 1');
$obj     = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

foreach ($columns as $column)
    $this->{$column} = $obj->{$column};
```

Make sure that `$columns` is not user input, as it is not escaped. You should also make sure `$id` is safe as well.

Comment: Why are the {} necessary around the property names? Wouldn't $this->$column = $obj->$column work?

Comment: It's not necessary, but I placed them in so that it could be changed to something such as `$this->{'prefix_'.$column}`. Assuming it's a class, loading all the columns into the class might replace something.